# Accessing JNDI Datasource using Container Managed Authentication Alias in Websphere (Spring + Ibatis/Mybatis)

Tags: websphere, datasource, ibatis, jaas

I am using WebSphere 8.5.5.18.

As of now I'm using Component-Managed Authentication Alias for my DataSource. But I want to use Container-Managed instead. When I just change the Security settings in **Data Sources** → **Security settings** I am getting error in logs. It is unable to fetch records.

[image: Security settings screenshot]

Exception Stacktrace:

```
Check the SQL Statement (preparation failed).  
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: [jcc][t4][10205][11234][3.72.54] Null userid is not supported. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 42815, Error Code = -4,461
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:97)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:212)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForObject(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:271)
```

Basically the database is not being accessed properly when settings are changed from Component-Managed Authentication to Container-Managed Authentication alias.

When I run with Component-Managed Authentication, its working fine.
Does changing security setting to Container Managed Authentication alias, require some other/additional setting/changes? Or do I need to change my underlying Spring ibatis code to make it work?

Any help on configuring/implementing Container-Managed Authentication Alias in websphere would be appreciated.

Comment: How does your Spring app obtain the datasource?  Injection?  Lookup?  A snippet showing the lookup code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Container-managed authentication applies when your code (or any third party code that executes upon its behalf) looks up the data source with a resource reference that specifies the resource authentication as container or leaves resource authentication unspecified, in which case it defaults to container.

Component-managed authentication applies when your code (or any third party code that executes upon its behalf) looks up the data source without a resource reference, or uses a resource reference that specifies the resource authentication as application.

Here are some examples of resource references that use container authentication:

```
// resource injection can be used on a web component (servlet) or ejb component
@Resource(name = "java:comp/env/jdbc/ds1ref", lookup = "jdbc/ds1", authenticationType = Resource.AuthenticationType.CONTAINER)
DataSource ds1;

@Resource(name = "java:comp/env/jdbc/ds2ref", lookup = "jdbc/ds2")
DataSource ds2;

...
// code that looks up one of the above resource references
DataSource ds = InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/ds1ref");
```

Here is an example of a resource reference defined within a web.xml deployment descriptor:

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>java:comp/env/jdbc/ds3ref</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  <lookup-name>jdbc/ds3</lookup-name>
</resource-ref>
```

If third party code, such as Spring, is looking up a data source on your behalf and you would like it to use container authentication, you will need to define a resource reference with container managed authentication, such as shown above in the examples, and supply its resource reference name to the third party software in place of however you are doing so currently.  If you are unsure where this is done, it might help to search for occurrences of the configured JNDI name of the WebSphere data source within the application.